# How does Vue.js detect the data on which a computed property depend on?

Tags: vue.js

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

You can data-bind to computed properties in templates just like a normal property. Vue is aware that vm.reversedMessage depends on vm.message, so it will update any bindings that depend on vm.reversedMessage when vm.message changes.

How does Vue.js does that? This has the smell of magic.

Comment: Vue is open source. You can look through it and find out if you want the nitty gritty details